# qt qcombobox shows no scroll bar

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox with an underlying model. Sometimes the model gets a couple of hundred of items, which makes it very difficult to scroll through the combobox. Is it somehow possible to add a scroll bar to the QComboBox? This would help a lot because my items are sorted.

I have read that QComboBox should come with a scroll bar by default, but this is not true in my case on my linux system. Is this the case with windows?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QComboBox` uses an `QAbstractItemView` (by default a `QListView` I think) for its popup. It's possible to call `view()` to get that widget. Since `QAbstractItemView` descends from `QAbstractScrollArea`, you can use all features from that class to modify how you want the scrollbars to show up.

As an extra, you can change this view to another type. For instance I have used a `QTreeView` in the past since it fit better with the data.

Comment: For any dummies (such as myself) reading along, if you have

my_widget = QComboBox()

then you need to write

my_widget.view().setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)